Unable to receive beacon events on iOS device using react-native-kontaktio library
I'm using the react-native-kontaktio library to scan for beacons (BLE) in my React Native app. The library works correctly on Android devices, but I'm encountering issues with iOS.
Here are my platform and library versions:

Platform: iOS
react-native: ^0.68.1
react-native-kontaktio: ^4.1.0

I'm trying to listen for beacon events using the following code:
kontaktEmitter.addListener('didRangeBeacons', ({ beacons, region }) => {
  // Event handling logic here
});

minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34

I have handled permission in info.plist like this --> 
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>'Description'</string>
        <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
        <string>'Description'</string>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>'Description'</string>
        <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Description</string>

code is like this --> 

const ScanBeacons: React.FC = () => {
  const [beaconsCount, setBeaconsCount] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(beaconSetup);
    return () => {
      // remove event listeners
      if (isAndroid) {
        kontaktEmitter.removeAllListeners('beaconsDidUpdate');
      } else {
        kontaktEmitter.removeAllListeners('didDiscoverDevices');
        kontaktEmitter.removeAllListeners('didRangeBeacons');
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const beaconSetup = async () => {
    if (isAndroid) {
      // Android
      const granted = await requestLocationPermission();
      if (granted) {
        await connect();
        await startScanning();
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          'Permission error',
          'Location permission not granted. Cannot scan for beacons',
          [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')}],
          {cancelable: false},
        );
      }
    } else {
      // iOS
      await init()
      .then(() => startDiscovery())
      .catch((error: Error) => Alert.alert('error', error.message));
  
      /**
       * Will discover Kontakt.io beacons only
       */
      await startDiscovery();
  
      /**
       * Works with any beacon(also virtual beacon, e.g. https://github.com/timd/MactsAsBeacon)
       * Requires user to allow GPS Location (at least while in use)
       *
       * change to match your beacon values
       */
      await startRangingBeaconsInRegion({
        identifier: '',
        // uuid: 'A4826DE4-1EA9-4E47-8321-CB7A61E4667E',
        uuid: 'my uuid', // my beacon uuid
        major: 1,
        minor: 34,
      });
    }
  
    // Add beacon listener
    if (isAndroid) {
      /* works with any beacon */
      DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
        'beaconsDidUpdate',
        async ({ beacons, region }) => {
          setBeaconsCount(beacons?.length);
          if(beacons?.length > 0){
            dispatch(
              setNearestBeacons({nearestBeacon: beacons[0]}),
            );
            if (isAndroid) {
                kontaktEmitter.removeAllListeners('beaconsDidUpdate');
            } else {
                kontaktEmitter.removeAllListeners('didDiscoverDevices');
                kontaktEmitter.removeAllListeners('didRangeBeacons');
            }
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      const nearestPosition = await checkNearestPosition();
      /* works with Kontakt.io beacons only */
      kontaktEmitter.addListener('didDiscoverDevices', ({ beacons }) => {
        
      });
  
      /* works with any beacon */
      kontaktEmitter.addListener('didRangeBeacons', ({ beacons, region }) => {
        
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>react-native-kontaktio Example</Text>
        <Text>{`Check console.log statements (connected beacons count: ${beaconsCount})`}</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};


